# How to save web audio streaming to file ( c++ / java )

Tags: java, c++, audio, streaming

is there any lib or well known method to save audio web streaming ( web radio , mp3 streaming)
to file programmatically ?

Comment: It depends on the type of stream. If it's a plain mp3-stream you really don't have to do anything. In those cases you can rip it by simply wgeting it. You need to provide more details.

Comment: its SHOUTcast  kind of streaming , i need to do it whitin my application cpp or java

Answer (score 2):

You could use libvlc from the [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) project. The [wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc) seems to be down right now though. The code is in c++.

**EDIT:** Found [this](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:m5f_NuGiRqYJ:wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial+libvlc+tutorial&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) and [this](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:s9h76cA_DDQJ:wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt+LibVLC+SampleCode&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) via google cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BASS library](http://www.un4seen.com). It has plenty of support for attaching to network streams and decode them into MP3/WMA/OGG/AAC files. Developed in C, but could easily be used in C++ and many other languages.

Comment: BASS Library is free for non-commerical use