# Can I programatically save the data stream sent to the sound card as a WAV file?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

In Windows XP, you can configure your sound card properties via the preloaded windows software.  In the recording properties, if "stereo mix" or "wave out" (or something similar) is selected as the recording device, programs that can record audio ("Sound Recorder" in windows for example) record a decent quality wave file of the audio stream.  I usually use Goldwave from download.com to do this as an example of a third-party application that functions the same.

Well, I've had trouble getting this scenario to happen on Windows Vista or later in a direct no-bullsh*t manner as described above.  It's more than just Vista+, it's also that some sound cards don't have that option at all.

I was just wondering if there is a way to run a windows-friendly program (VB?) that takes your audio output stream and converts it (in realtime, obviously) to a WAV file with the default sampling rate as other WAV files have.

Ideally, it would cool if it worked on any operating system, so is it possible to write a web service that "listens" to your audio card like that without making the computer think it's getting a virus attack or something?

Possibly related question:
[How to save web audio streaming to file ( c++ / java )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090695/how-to-save-web-audio-streaming-to-file-c-java)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only aware of one manufacturer of sound cards that enabled that option (Creative).  However Vista and beyond support a "loopback" mode which gives you effectively the same functionality.  You need to use the low level WASAPI rendering stack but it *should* work just fine.

Comment: expand on that... i lost you at "low level WASAPI rendering stack".  I'll look it up, but let me know how it applies here with some more detail please

Comment: http://www.letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=wasapi
http://www.letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=wasapi loopback

First hit on the second link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx

Comment: i dont know if i'm doing something wrong, but this doesnt work on xp for me

Comment: CheeseConQueso: Did you see my comment about Vista and beyond?  This functionality isn't available on XP - it's up to the driver manufacturer to provide it on XP and very few driver manufacturers did.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rdp/virtual-audio-output-sniffer provides a directshow input device to capture the sum of wave out for vista+

Answer (score 0):

You could use low level waveOut API injection and capture what it receives.

I have SkypeMXrecorder, a software that does just that - inject into any exe and 'sniffs' what's going out from it and into the sound hardware.  But, it seems rather complicated to implement...